# while dragging draggable element show ids under it

Tags: jquery, get, element, ids

I am using a touch-punch jquery element and I need to somehow now/get the ids of the underlying elements over which the element is moving so that I can change their classes. I have created 6 differenet squares with relevant ids amd I want to actively be taking the id while the draggable element is being dragged over them. I am actually try to simulate the hover action but for a touch screen. I also include the relevant script. Any ideas? thnx.

```css
#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div5 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div6 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#circle_pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: rgba(255, 85, 255, 1);
}

#containment_wrapper {
  width: 610px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<p id="coordinates">coordinates</p>
<p id="div_id"></p>

<div id="circle_pointer"></div>

<div id="containment_wrapper">
  <div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
  </div>
</div>



<script>

  $(function() {
    $("#circle_pointer").draggable({
      containment: "#containment_wrapper",

      drag: function() {
        $("#circle_pointer").addClass("sc"),
          $("#map_container").addClass("sc1"),

          x = $("#circle_pointer").position(),
          $("#coordinates").html(x.top + ' , ' + x.left),
          $("#div_id").html("div_id")
      },

      stop: function() {
        $("#circle_pointer").removeClass("sc")

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) to get the element which is currently dragged over. For `x.top` values that are near the bottom border this returns `null`, therefore I provided a check for this to prevent any issues. Note that I changed the ids you're using as you have duplicate ids while ids have to be unique.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#circle_pointer").draggable({
    containment: "#containment_wrapper",

    drag: function() {
      $("#circle_pointer").addClass("sc"),
        $("#map_container").addClass("sc1"),

        x = $("#circle_pointer").position(),
        $("#coordinates").html(x.top + ' , ' + x.left),
        getId(x.top, x.left)

    },
    stop: function() {
      $("#circle_pointer").removeClass("sc")
    }
  });

  function getId(x, y) {

    var element = document.elementFromPoint(y, x);
      if (element != null) {
       var id = element.id;
        $("#div_id").html(id);
      }
  }

});
```

```css
#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div5 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#div6 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#circle_pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: rgba(255, 85, 255, 1);
}

#containment_wrapper {
  width: 610px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<p id="coordinates">coordinates</p>
<p id="div_id"></p>

<div id="circle_pointer"></div>

<div id="containment_wrapper">
  <div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
    <div id="div5"></div>
    <div id="div6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx Matthias, that was helpful. Do you have any idea how the same could be done if I needed to know the id of the item at the centre of the circle. When I change the coordinates x.top and x.left I get the id of the cicle_pointer but I actually need the id of the item below (the one with z-index under it).

Comment: @mike I suggest the following: https://jsfiddle.net/b1qapzvf/ I added 30px to the top and left position as the circle has 60 px height and width, so this should be the position of the middle of the circle. Then I used elementsFromPoint which returns all elements at that position and excluded the circle and the wrapper element to get the div.

Comment: Thnx @Matthias once more! And one more question. If i want to change the class (for example change the color) of the div under it for example $("#id").addClass("class") but only when the centre of the circle is over it (something  relevant to the hover effect on desktop) an then remove that class so that the class is added only on the underlying div?

Comment: @mike You could do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6ar0ndhv/ Note that it's sometimes a bit buggy in the Fiddle but I checked it on a standalone page and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I also have one more very simple question but it does not work for me. Intead of just displaying the div_id I need to display "Now you are over id:" div 1. I simply defined a new variable div_now =  "Now you are over id:" + id; but id appears undefined. When id is alone it is didplayed fine (this is how it works now) but when I place another string it seems undefined. Do you know why this happens and how it is overcomed? thnx onve more.

Comment: @mike I don't know why this happens but here is a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/j3bus1fe/